# how to get document by Id from collectionGroup

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

my database look like this

- users(collection)

  - user_id(document)

    - images(collection)

      - image_id(document)

i used collectionGroup to reach all images collection and now i want get the image by id.

```
Firestore.instance.collectionGroup('images').document('$imageid').get().then((onValue){
```

but with `collectionGroup()` there's no `document()`

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift** language, I would go like this:

```
// (tested and confirmed)

Firestore.firestore().collectionGroup("users").getDocuments { (doc, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print(err?.localizedDescription)
            }
            if doc?.isEmpty == false {
                for doc in doc!.documents {
                    print("DOC = ", doc.documentID)
                }
            }
        }
```

I don't use **Dart**, but I found this online for you. You might have to tweak it so it compiles for you.  I know it's using collection instead of collectionGroup.

```
 final collRef = Firestore.instance.collection('images');
 DocumentReferance docReferance = collRef.document();

  docReferance.setData(map).then((doc) {
    print('hop ${docReferance.documentID}');
  }).catchError((error) {
    print(error);
  });
]
```